# Баг swiper js на мобильном устройстве (остановка свайпинга после перехода на второй слайд)

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper

Я создал сайт с использованием Swiper JS. В desktop версии все работает нормально, но в мобильной версии на 2-м слайде регистрация свайпов вверх и вниз останавливается. Вот ссылка на сайт: https://bytenex.tech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в выставленом параметре

```
    pointer-events:none
```